# Avoiding duplicates when using a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, duplicates

I have a basic data frame containing 4 letters in a column:

```
a
b
c
d
```

I wish to use a nested for-loop to bind each letter with every other letter in a new data frame, but avoid binding one letter to itself and avoid duplicates. So far, I can avoid the former but am having trouble with the latter. My code looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
e <- data.frame()

for (j in d[,1]) {
  
  for (i in d[,1]) {
    
    if (j != i) {
      e <- rbind(e, c(j, i))
    }
  }
}
```

This produces the following:

```
a b #this row
a c
a d
b a #and this row are duplicates
b c
b d
c a
c b
c d
d a
d b
d c
```

I wish to use the nested for-loop to produce:

```
a b
a c
a d
b c
b d
c d
```

I know that having the for-loop run by moving down one row each time (in data frame d) could potentially work, but I am not sure how to code that. I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: For future consideration when coding combinations/permutations, you may also want to consider the very nice combinations and permutations functions in the gtools package: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.5.0/topics/combinations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case of `combn` and this can be done easily without a loop

```
t(combn(d[[1]], 2))
```

-output

```
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "a"  "b" 
#[2,] "a"  "c" 
#[3,] "a"  "d" 
#[4,] "b"  "c" 
#[5,] "b"  "d" 
#[6,] "c"  "d"
```

---

If the OP wanted to use loop, add some conditions

```
e <- data.frame(col1 = "", col2 = "")

for (j in d[,1]) {  
  for (i in d[,1]) {    
    if (j != i) {
       
         i1 <- !(any((i == e[[1]] & j == e[[2]])))
         
         i2 <- !(any((j %in% e[[1]] && i %in% e[[2]])))
         
         if(i1 & i2) {
          
         e <- rbind(e, c(j, i))
         
    }
  }
}
}
```

-output

```
e[-1,]
col1 col2
2    a    b
3    a    c
4    a    d
5    b    c
6    c    d
7    d    b
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer akrun, but I am using this nested for loop as a proxy for a much larger dataset for statistical analysis.

Comment: @MatinBozorg Do you really wanted to change your original script or are you okay with `duplicated` i.e. `e[!duplicated(pmin(e[[1]], e[[2]]), pmax(e[[1]], e[[2]])),]`

Comment: I would be ok changing the original script as long as it can work with the nested for-loop.

Comment: @LyricalStats9 i would say by performance wise, the duplicated would be much faster

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the suggestion of @akrun.
As a rule of thumb, there is almost never the need in R to use loops for any kind of string (or generally any) manipulation of data.

See this speed comparison:

```
d <- data.frame(c(letters))
e <- data.frame()

solutionCustom <- function(x){
  for (j in d[,1]) {
    for (i in d[,1]) {
      if (j != i) {
        e <- rbind(e, c(j, i))
      }
    }
  }
  e
}

solutionCombn <- function(x) t(combn(d[,1], 2))

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(solutionCustom=solutionCustom(),
               solutionCombn=solutionCombn())

Unit: microseconds
           expr       min        lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
 solutionCustom 44769.620 48898.410 54423.5789 54018.3875 57949.8755 76922.178   100
  solutionCombn   238.311   267.486   294.4763   286.2005   305.8805   605.728   100
```

The `combn` solution is about 188x faster and less code-writing-intensive. Whevener you have to use loops in R there is a good chance that you are missing a much more efficient solution.